# Convert 64x uint8_t to 64x float using Intel AVX-512 intrinsics

Tags: c++, intel, intrinsics, avx512

I have allocated `uint8_t` memory like:

```
uint8_t* srcPtr = malloc( sizeof( uint8 ) * 64 );
```

`srcPtr` is the input for my **test function**, which is multiplied with a user-given single-precision float (e.g. `9.0`).

##### Scalar Code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i ++)
    srcPtr[i] *= float_value;
```

In order to multiply with `float_value`, I think I need to convert each `uint8_t` to `float` to use AVX-512 intrinsics.
Using AVX-512 Intel intrinsics, is there any way to load 64x `uint8_t` to float AVX-512 vectors directly instead of too many instruction like this:

##### Intrinsics Code

```cpp
__m512i px = _mm512_loadu_si512((__m512i *)srcPtr);

__m128i input[4];
input[0] = _mm512_extracti32x4_epi32(px, 0);
input[1] = _mm512_extracti32x4_epi32(px, 1);
input[2] = _mm512_extracti32x4_epi32(px, 2);
input[3] = _mm512_extracti32x4_epi32(px, 3);

__m512i output[4];
output[0] = _mm512_cvtepu8_epi32(input[0]);
output[1] = _mm512_cvtepu8_epi32(input[1]);
output[2] = _mm512_cvtepu8_epi32(input[2]);
output[3] = _mm512_cvtepu8_epi32(input[3]);

__m512 p[4];
p[0] = _mm512_cvtepu32_ps(output[0]);
p[1] = _mm512_cvtepu32_ps(output[1]);
p[2] = _mm512_cvtepu32_ps(output[2]);
p[3] = _mm512_cvtepu32_ps(output[3]);
```

Comment: If you used your intrinsics code, you would end up with 64 floats in the end. Do you actually want that, or do you want to modify your 64 uint8_t's in-place? If it's meant to be in-place, you're probably better off converting the float to 64 bytes and multiplying.

Comment: Do you need the full 23bit precision of `float`, or can you work, e.g., with a 8+8bit fixed-point scalar? You could consider doing fixed-point multiplication. So instead of converting `uint8->int32->float->mulps->int32->uint8`, just do `uint8->uint16->pmulhw->uint8`

Comment: If you can target AVX-512-BF16 or AVX512-FP16, you can use that for twice the data density, only needing 2 vectors, and still allowing multipliers that aren't whole integers.  But `pmulhw` with an appropriately-scaled version of `9` to put the result you want in the high half of a multiply avoids the need to convert and back, just unpack / repack.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++, please. And try to stay away from manual memory management in general in modern C++.

Comment: yes. I need all entire 23 precision of float @chtz. Is there any other way to convert from int to float?

Comment: @AI-developer conversion from `[u]int32` to `float` is straight-forward. For `uint8->float` you can also consider blending/merging the lower byte with a float which equals `1<<23`, then subtract that float-value from it (ideally this can be fused with sub-sequent operations into a single FMA) -- it depends on context whether this is more efficient. But I doubt that for `uint8 x; float s; x*=s;` you need 23bit precision.

Comment: @chtz direct conversion focused in comment is for scaler code I suppose. Is there any intrinsics instruction available for same apart from which I tried above?. One more thing, once float is multiplied, again it will be converted uint8t. So input and output is uint8t

Comment: For conversion back to uint8, do you assume that no overflow occurs? Otherwise, do you want saturation or wrap-around behavior? Is rounding to nearest instead of truncation ok?

Comment: yes @chtz. That should be fine. Any instruction available for the steps